# Is it necessary to use using block inside a using block?

Tags: c#, .net

I have some code just like below. I am using my `sql connection class` in a `using` block. When it finishes the job, it disposes the connection as it is supposed to do. I also have some kernel classes in the same using block and i want them to get disposed when the using block that they are in finishes the job.

I searched a little bit but couldn't find an answer. Does the `using` block dispose all objects that are inside it's blocks or does it just dispose the object that wrote as parameter? I hope i asked properly. I just want to understand and i don't want to keep writing unnecessary using blocks.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=" + serverName + ";initial catalog=" +
                                                      dataBase + ";integrated security=false;uid=" +
                                                      sqlUser + ";password=" + sqlPass + ";"))
{
    Kernel kernel = new Kernel();
    Sirket sirket = default(Sirket);
    Fatura fatura = default(Fatura);
    try
    {
        sirket = kernel.yeniSirket(TVTTipi.vtMSSQL,
                                      "vt adı",
                                      "vt kull adı",
                                      "vt kull sifre",
                                      "netsis kull adı",
                                      "netsis kull sifre",
                                      sube kodu);
        fatura = kernel.yeniFatura(sirket, TFaturaTip.ftSFat);
        fatura.OkuUst("A00000000000011", "C0001");
        fatura.OkuKalem();
        fatura.kayitSil();
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(fatura);// those are releasing the objects. if i didn't use those methods would they get disposed immediately as using block finishes.
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sirket);
        kernel.FreeNetsisLibrary();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(kernel);
    }

}
```

Comment: multiple using blocks needed, using will only dispose the `IDisposable` that u put in the brackets: e.g. using(xxxx) - only xxx gets disposed, nothing else inside will, to further clarify, my answer is with regards to `IDisposables` that need to get closed, normal GC will work on objects within the using. So for example if within your sql connecting u opened a `Stream` u would have to put that in a `using` as well

Comment: Also, new with C# 8 is the using declaration. It allows you to declare a variable as using like so `using var conn = new SqlConnection(...);` without having a using block. It will then automatically dispose of every variable declared like this once the variable goes out of scope

Comment: @MindSwipe mmm c#8 ftw, i like that

Comment: Please note that niether of the instances inside the using statement gets disposed in the code sample in the question. `Dispose` is not the same as `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`...

Comment: Is the question: "Can I use `using` statement instead of `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`" ? The answer is nope, but you can easily make own wrapper class to abuse (in a good way) `IDisposable` and achieve that.

Answer (score 4):

No, `using` will only dispose the one object.

However, nested using blocks can be written like this:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection())
using (var kernel = new Kernel())
{
    // ...
} // Disposes kernel and con
```

Note that COM objects are not released with `using`. For that, you need the finally block as written. Just put the dispose call there, too.

An alternative would be a wrapper, that also frees the COM object. Outline:

```
class ComReleaseWrapper : IDisposable
{
    object _obj;
    public ComReleaseWrapper(object o) {
       _obj = o;
    }
    public object Object { get { return _obj; } }

    public void Dispose() {
        if (_obj != null) {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_obj);
            if (_obj is IDisposable d) d.Dispose();
        }
        _obj = null;
    }
 }

 using (var kernelWrap = new ComReleaseWrapper(new Kernel()) {
    var kernel = kernelWrap.Object as Kernel;
 }
```

Comment: Mind that `kernel` is a COM Object. OP is doing `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(kernel);`. As Sinatr writes correctly, it could be wrapped in an IDisposable, though.

Comment: You're right, didn't pay attention to that... In that case, I would actually prefer the finally block with explicit dispose if this is a one time use case. Otherwise, a wrapper class would be a good solution

Answer (score 1):

It disposes only the variable defined as in this case would be `SqlConnection`. If you have multiple items to dispose you could however stack them as follows to keep the code better readable:

```
using (var f1 = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\file.txt", FileMode.Open))
using (var f2 = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\file.txt", FileMode.Open))
using (var f3 = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\file.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    //do stuff with filestreams here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The using block only disposes the object initialized in the parenthesis.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    // Do all sort of stuff here with other disposable things
} // At this point in the code, only the SqlConnection gets disposed.
```

The using block is syntactic sugar for `try...finally` - so the previous code actually gets translated to this:

```
var  conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
try
{
    // Do all sort of stuff here with other disposable things
}
finally
{
    // At this point in the code, only the SqlConnection gets disposed.
    ((IDisposable)conn).Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not necessary to use using inside using.

It is a wrapper so that we don't have to explicitly dispose object.